# gnu make - how to define variables in foreach based on some condition

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to assign variables in foreach loop based on some condition.

For example in practice I want to use it for going through all required tools (gcc g++ as ld) check if they are found on system path. If yes then keep it, if not then try to add user provided path prefix and if it can be found there then modify variable to use full path else report early error to the user.

Answer (score 3):

In general answer I come up with:

```
TEST_ARRAY = AA BB
K := $(foreach myTest,$(TEST_ARRAY),\
        $(if $(filter AA,$(myTest)),\
            $(eval $(myTest) := match),\
            $(eval $(myTest) := mismatch)))

$(info "AA: ${AA}")
$(info "BB: ${BB}")
```

the output is:

```
"AA: match"
"BB: mismatch"
```

answer to my more specific question is quite longer - the working code snippet is like this:

```
#on widows
DEVNUL := NUL
WHICH := where
#on linux
#DEVNUL := /dev/null
#WHICH := which

# set path to be searched when command is not found in system PATH
GNU_PATH := c:\NSS\GNU_Tools_ARM_Embedded\5.4 2016q3\bin2
# optionally set command prefix - for example all your tools are not called "gcc" but "arm-gcc" so you would fill here "arm-" 
GNU_PREFIX := arm-none-eabi-
# set command suffix - for example on windows all executable files have suffix ".exe" 
GNU_SUFFIX := .exe

# escape spaces in path because make $(wildcard ) can not handle them :(
empty :=
space := $(empty) $(empty)
GNU_PATH_ESCAPED := $(subst  $(space),\ ,$(GNU_PATH))

# define used tool-chain commands
CC              := gccx
AS              := as
AR              := ar
LD              := ld
NM              := nm
OBJDUMP         := objdump
OBJCOPY         := objcopy
SIZE            := size

# detect if tool-chain commands are installed and fill correct path (prefer system PATH, then try to find them in suggested GNU_PATH)
# if not found on neither system path nor on user provided GNU_PATH then early error is reported to user
EXECUTABLES = CC AS AR LD NM OBJDUMP OBJCOPY SIZE
$(foreach myTestCommand,$(EXECUTABLES),\
    $(if $(shell ${WHICH} ${GNU_PREFIX}$($(myTestCommand)) 2>${DEVNUL} ),\
        $(eval $(myTestCommand) := ${GNU_PREFIX}$($(myTestCommand))),\
        $(if $(wildcard $(GNU_PATH_ESCAPED)\${GNU_PREFIX}$($(myTestCommand))$(GNU_SUFFIX)),\
            $(eval $(myTestCommand) := '$(GNU_PATH)/${GNU_PREFIX}$($(myTestCommand))$(GNU_SUFFIX)'),\
            $(error "Can not find tool ${GNU_PREFIX}$($(myTestCommand))$(GNU_SUFFIX), either make in in your system PATH or provide correct path in variable GNU_PATH"))))

# just print what tools will be used
$(foreach myTestCommand,$(EXECUTABLES),\
    $(info found tool $($(myTestCommand))))

default:
    @$(CC) --version
```

in my test case I have all tools on my path except `gccx` which is located in my user folder provided in `GNU_PATH`.

```
found tool 'c:\NSS\GNU_Tools_ARM_Embedded\5.4 2016q3\bin2/arm-none-eabi-gccx.exe'
found tool arm-none-eabi-as
found tool arm-none-eabi-ar
found tool arm-none-eabi-ld
found tool arm-none-eabi-nm
found tool arm-none-eabi-objdump
found tool arm-none-eabi-objcopy
found tool arm-none-eabi-size
```